# Bootstrap 3 radio button correct syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have been in the process of migrating my current project from Bootstrap 2.3 to Bootstrap 3 which has had some major structural changes particularly to due with radio buttons. Currently I have

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">                            
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="emViewMacsButton" name="options" type="radio">MAC
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="emViewTagsButton" name="options" type="radio">Tags
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="emViewSettingsButton" name="options" type="radio">Settings
  </label>
</div>
```

**Script Code:**

```
$('#emViewMacsButton').on('click',emViewMacs());
$('#emViewTagsButton').on('click',emViewTags());                      
$('#emViewSettingsButton').on('click',emViewSettings());
```

My problem lies in that I have setup my program that each of the different radio buttons must access a different function to display table data. The `.on('click')` function returns nothing. I've also tried `$('input[name=options]')` but the active attribute isn't set for any of the radio buttons on the returned piece of HTML .
What would be the correct structure for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/uwezip/1/edit

when passing a function ( `myFunction()` ) into another function callback, just remove the `()`

```
$(function(){ // DOM is now ready to be manipulated

    $('#emViewMacsButton').on('change',emViewMacs);
    $('#emViewTagsButton').on('change',emViewTags);                      
    $('#emViewSettingsButton').on('change',emViewSettings);

});
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference as the <input> HTML tags don't seem to respond to the .on('click') or .click() methods.

Comment: @MikeMeding have you wrapped your code into `document ready` function ?

Comment: With or without wrapping it into document ready doesn't make a difference either. I really think it has something to do with the way I have my listeners set up. I really wish Bootstrap 3 had better documentation than this for radio buttons...

Comment: Well, at least hope you learned something useful from this one ;)

Comment: Seeming as bootstrap 3 was released about a week ago it makes sense that there will be some quirks with it but this one has become particularly frustrating.